# Looking for A Regular expression to match java regex (punct) pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for help/support for a Regex  expression which will match studentIdMatch2 value in below class. studentIdMatch1 matches fine.However the studentIdMatch2 has studentId which can allow all the special characters other than : and ^ and comma.Hence its not working,thank you for your time and appreciate your support.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestRegEx {
    public static void main(String args[]){

       String studentIdMatch1 = "studentName:harry,^studentId:Id123";
       String studentIdMatch2 = "studentName:harry,^studentId:Id-H/MPU/L&T/OA+_T/(1490)/17@)123";
       Pattern pattern = Pattern
                .compile("(\\p{Punct}?)(\\w+?)(:)(\\p{Punct}?)(\\w+?)(\\p{Punct}?),");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(studentIdMatch1 + ","); // Works Fine(Matches Student Name and Id)
                                                                        // No Special Characters in StudentId
        //Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(studentIdMatch2 + ","); //Wont work Special Characters in StudentId. Matches Student Name
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("group1 = "+matcher.group(1)+ "group2 = "+matcher.group(2) +"group3 = "+matcher.group(3) +"group4 = "+matcher.group(4)+"group5 = "+matcher.group(5));
        }
        System.out.println("match ended");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please try `^SutdentName:(\w+),\^StudenId:([^\s,^:]+)$` Demo: https://regex101.com/r/A5OtsQ/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
^SutdentName:(\w+),\^StudenId:([^\s,^:]+)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
- **`SutdentName:`** - Matches `SutdentName:` literally. **Although according to me it should be StudentName; but I didn't changed it.**
- **`(\w+)`** - Represents first capturing group matching only word characters i.e. `[A-Za-z0-9_]` one or more times **greedily**.
- **`,\^StudenId:`** - Matches `,^StudenId` literally. Here also I guess it should be StudentId.
- **`([^\s,^:]+)`** - Represents second capturing group matching everything other than white-space, `,`, `^` and `:` one or more times **greedily**. You can add others according to your requirements.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/A5OtsQ/4/)

**Sample Implementation in java:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class Main
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^SutdentName:(\\w+),\\^StudenId:([^\\s,^:]+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String string = "SutdentName:harry,^StudenId:Id123\n"
     + "SutdentName:harry,^StudenId:Id-H/MNK/U&T/BA+_T/(1490)/17@)123";
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
     while(matcher.find()){
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
     }
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/ByYNsgR0I)

Answer (score 0):

The second `(\\w+?)` only captures words. So change it to capture what you want. i.e

> allow all the special characters other than : and ^ and comma

like `([^:^,]+?)`

- `^` - Negate the match
- `:^,` - Matches `:` , `^` and `comma`

Comment: Nice answer +1; btw there is no need of `?`(greedy match is fine).

Comment: I just wanted to help with minimal changes to OP's post